# select one column which has the same properties with the other column

Tags: mysql, sql, database

hello everyone!  There is a table contains just 3 columns('playerID', 'teamID' and 'yearID')

I just want to get the columns which have the same year and on the same team of one player. You can see the codes as follow:

```
Select playerID, teamID, yearID
FROM `appearancessmall`
WHERE (teamID IN 
(SELECT teamID from  `appearancessmall` WHERE playerID = 'napolmi01' )  
) AND
(yearID  IN (SELECT yearID from  `appearancessmall` WHERE playerID = 
'napolmi01')
)
```

But the output of the query is the total columns which have the same teamID or the same yearID with the player"napolmi01", what I want is the columns be selected should satisfy the two requirements at the same time. So how to do that?

Comment: Have a read about JOINs

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try combining the 2 subqueries and comparing both columns at the same time:

```
SELECT
   playerID
 , teamID
 , yearID
FROM `appearancessmall`
WHERE 
  (teamID,yearID) IN (
   SELECT teamID,yearID
   FROM `appearancessmall`
   WHERE playerID = 'napolmi01'
   )
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use a `LEFT JOIN` like in the below example

```
SELECT `et`.* FROM `test` `t`
LEFT JOIN `test` `et`
ON `t`.`teamID`=`et`.`teamID` AND `t`.`yearID`=`et`.`yearID`
WHERE `t`.`playerID`='napolmi01';
```

Try it out on [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b7d9d1/3)

Comment: Thanks for your answer from another method, I test it and it is really good, but the answer by@Used_By_Already is a little earlier, so I take that answer as the answer, please forgive me, by the way, thank you very much!

Comment: @JacksonTom my query is not the only alternative way, there are more. In this case though it is more proper to use a join. Anyway cheers :)